# alternative to compiler.ast.getChildNodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-construction

Is there any alternative I can use from the ast module to the method

```
compiler.ast.getChildNodes()
```

I would not want to use the compiler package since its deprecated and not supported in the later versions. I'm using Python 2.7 though